# Does {{#if}} affect the context?

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

I have a helper function that does error checking when getting a property from an object (converted from a sample on stackoverflow):

```
module.exports.register = function (Handlebars, options) {

  Handlebars.registerHelper('get', function (obj, prop, context) {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object') {
      throw new Error('get: Cannot get from ' + typeof obj);
    }

    if (typeof prop !== 'string') {
      throw new Error('get: Property must be a string. Type ' + typeof prop + ' not supported');
    }

    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      throw new Error('get: Object does not contain the property "' + prop + '"');
    }

    return obj[prop];
  });
}
```

When I use this normally it works just fine:

```
<div>
  {{get ../site.sectionNames tag}}
</div>
```

...however, if I place it within an `{{#if true}}` element, then `obj` is undefined:

```
<div>
  {{#if true}}
    {{get ../site.sectionNames tag}}
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

I was under the impression that `{{#if}}` [doesn't change the context](http://assemble.io/docs/Context.html). **Why is this happening?**

Comment: This appears to be expected behaviour: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/196.

Comment: Thanks, I added a comment to see if I can figure out why this is happening. Seems to directly conflict with the documentation...

Answer (score 1):

Consider following example.
..

**Context:**

```
{
  id: 1,
  items: ['a', 'b']
}
```

**Template 1:**

```
{{#each items}}
  <div>outer: {{../id}}</div>
  {{#if ../id}}
    <div>inner: {{../id}}</div>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

*Output:*

```
outer: 1  
inner:  
outer: 1  
inner:
```

**Template 2:** - (without outer #each block)

```
<div>outer: {{id}}</div>
{{#if id}}
    <div>inner: {{id}}</div>
{{/if}}
```

*Output:*

```
outer: 1
inner: 1
```

So, I think it is `#each` which creates this inconsistency.

`../` gives us the context outside current block and not the parent context in JSON. And for `#if` block, inner and outside context may or may not be same.

So, to be consistent and avoid any confusion, we should always add `../` for referring to values inside `#if` block.
For example,

```
{{#if id}}
   {{../id}}
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Blocks create a new context.  So - the inner `{{#if}}` is within the context of `{{#each}}` - not the root context.

In other words, you can use:

```
{{#each items}}
    <div>outer: {{../id}}</div>
    {{#if ../id}}
        <div>inner: {{../../id}}</div>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

You can also try `@root`:

```
{{#each items}}
    <div>outer: {{ @root.id}}</div>
    {{#if @root.id}}
        <div>inner: {{ @root.id}}</div>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```